# deploy kubernetes ingress with terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I'm trying deploy kubernetes ingress with terraform.
As described here [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/ingress#example-using-nginx-ingress-controller) and my own variant:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "node" {
  metadata {
    name = "node"
  }
  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "nginx"
    rule {
      host = "backend.io"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/"
          backend {
            service_name = kubernetes_service.node.metadata.0.name
            service_port = 3000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

error:

```
╷
│ Error: Failed to create Ingress 'default/node' because: the server could not find the requested resource (post ingresses.extensions)
│ 
│   with kubernetes_ingress.node,
│   on node.tf line 86, in resource "kubernetes_ingress" "node":
│   86: resource "kubernetes_ingress" "node" {
│ 
╵
```

it works:

kubectl apply -f file_below.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: node
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: backend.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
            service:
              name: node
              port:
               number: 3000
```

Need some ideas about how to deploy kubernetes ingress with terraform.

Comment: Have you defined the provider block in terraform code and if so can you add that to the question as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that the example in YML is using the proper API version, i.e., `networking.k8s.io/v1`, hence it works as you probably have a version of K8s higher than 1.19. It is available since that version, the `extensions/v1beta1` that Ingress was a part of was deprecated in favor of `networking.k8s.io/v1` in 1.22, as you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122). As that is the case, your current Terraform code is using the old K8s API version for Ingress. You can see that on the left-hand side of the documentation menu:

[image: extensionsv1beta1]

If you look further down in the documentation, you will see `networking/v1` and in the [resource section](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/ingress_v1) `kubernetes_ingress_v1`. Changing the code you have in Terraform to use Ingress from the `networking.k8s.io/v1`, it becomes:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "node" {
  metadata {
    name = "node"
  }

  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "nginx"
    rule {
      host = "backend.io"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/*"
          path_type = "ImplementationSpecific"
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service.node.metadata.0.name
              port {
                number = 3000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---